# How to create a data frame that contains dates and NAs

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a df with 
columns = c("Tim", "Tom", "Peter") 
the rows display a certain productID.

When Tim buyes product 1, then the df[1,1] should be something like 2019-08-01 and the the rest of the df is filled with NAs.

I Created the df with some values in it. The date values are displayed in numeric form like 18109. And I tried to transform it into "2019-08-01" as date.

```
df[1,1:5] <- as.Date("18109", format = "%Y-%m-%d")
Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied

as.Date(KundenBestelldf$Tim, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
#results in a list of NAs and the date is deleted when I am looking for head()


df[1,1:5] <- as.Date("18109", format = "%Y-%m-%d")
#Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied

as.Date(df$Tim, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
#results in a list of NAs and the date is deleted when I am looking for 
head()

#the code to reproduce is:

#create customer vector
names <- c("Tim", "Tom", "Peter")
ID <- c(1:6)
names(ID) <- names

#matrix
matrix <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = 255, ncol = 6)

colnames(matrix) <- names

df <- data.frame(matrix)
class(df) #class is now data.frame

df[1,1:5] <- as.Date(as.integer("18109"),format = "%Y-%m-%d", origin = 
"1970-01-01")
#the class is actually numeric and now I can not transform it to date
```

Comment: The `format` argument of `as.Date` is intended to tell R what the input format is. `18109` is not in YYYY-MM-DD format, so `format = "%Y-%m-%d"` is incorrect. Instead, try specifying the origin as the error indicates (standard origin is 1970-01-01). `as.Date(18109, origin = "1970-01-01")` works fine. I see you have quotes around "18109", so if you *need* to use a character input, convert to integer first, `as.Date(as.integer("18109"), origin = "1970-01-01")`

Comment: You may also be having problems because of column classes and conversions - in fact if the `class` is `Date` and the display is 18109, your problem may be a `print` method problem, not a class / conversion problem. Would you share a sample data frame with 3-5 rows for illustrative purposes? Either share the code to create it, or share it with `dput()` (e.g., `dput(df[1:3, ])` so it is copy/pasteable and the true column classes and structure are preserved.